# assign two character arrays in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a[100];
    char c[1];
    cin >> a;
    c[0] = a[8];
    cout << c;
}
```

input: `asdfghjklmn`
output: `lasdfghjklmn`

I don't understand how it does element assignment.

Comment: `cout<<c[0];`, otherwise C++ expect a NUL `'\0'` terminated sequence, which `char c[1];` isn't.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "element assignment". But the subsequent use of `<<` results in undefined behavior. How do your C++ textbook describe the `<<` overload for a plain character pointer, and how it must be used? And, by the way, which C++ textbook told you to use `bits/stdc++.h`? This is not a standard C++ header file, this is bad textbook. You should get rid of it and get a better textbook that teacher proper, standard, C++.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
```

Don't. This header is non-standard, non-portable, leads to terrible compilation times and is all around a bad habit born from "competitive" coding sites that revel in bad habits. `#include <iostream>` (i.e., including only what you actually use) would be better in *all* respects.

```
using namespace std;
```

Also [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Try to keep your namespace minimal.

```
int main(){
    char a[100];
```

No. Don't. [`<string>` exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string). `char[]` is a C string, a thing of backward compatibility. In C++, a "string" is a `std::string` object. There is nothing "elite" about using C constructs in C++ code, just lots of potential errors and mistakes.

```
    char c[1];
    cin>>a;
    c[0]=a[8];
```

You do not check that `a` actually *has* a character at that index...

```
    cout<<c;
}
```

`c` is not (and, due to its one-byte size, cannot be) null-terminated, i.e. not a string. Yet `cout << c` treats it as one and will keep printing characters from memory until it hits a zero byte; you're looking at undefined behavior. *In this case* `c` sits in memory right before `a`, so you see `c` and `a` printed subsequently, but that is in no way guaranteed. One of those things you completely avoid when actually using the language, i.e. `<string>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    std::string c;

    std::cin >> a;

    if ( a.length() > 8 )
    {
        c.push_back( a[8] );
    }

    std::cout << c;
}
```

There you go.